# Long latencies between Azure IOT Hub and Function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function app (Consumption Plan) consuming events from IOT Hub. About 20 devices upload a few events every 10 secs using HTTP POST to IOT Hub.

The IOT Hub has 2 consumer groups (coldpath & hotpath). A ColdPath AF consumes from the coldpath consumer group in order to simply save events to Azure Tables. The HotPath function consumes from the hotpath consumer group and updates 'realtime' stats, etc, saving the results in other Azure Tables.

I calculate latency (time from IOT Hub enqueue to function app triggering) as DateTime.UtcNow - eventData.EnqueuedTimeUtc.

It is here that I am experiencing huge delays of up to a day which is not acceptable. The execution duration of the HotPath and ColdPath functions are sub-second (HotPath ~80msec). Any suggestions of how to find the issue as I am 'blind' with respect to where the events get stuck. No place in Azure to see this.

Comment: have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---scaling, also how many partitions is setup? what about the cold start for azure function, https://mikhail.io/2018/04/azure-functions-cold-starts-in-numbers/  and https://mikhail.io/2018/05/azure-functions-cold-starts-beyond-first-load/

Comment: I have read all of the docs and is familiar with the cold start cost. Each of the devices (~20) call an HTTP function in that same FunctionApp every 1 sec. This would act as the 'keep warm'. Even though I have that, each device sends data every 10 secs. So I think it is unlikely that it would be cold start. Latencies of 1 day does not really point to cold start issues I think. EDIT: currently 4 partitions

Comment: I have agree, the AF cold starts can not be the issue, For the test purposes: enable Diagnostics settings for storage account with Log:DeviceTelemetry also for consuming side, add one more consuming group for a simple streaming job (for instance: select * into outputBlob from iothub) and have a look at its metrics and outputBlob, how the events are consumed, etc. The point of this test is to verify how is working a checkpoint of the event hub for ASA job, see more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-consumers

Comment: @RomanKiss: I enabled the Log:DeviceTelemetry in the IOT Hub and will monitor. Not exactly sure about your 2nd suggestion? Adding the consumer group I am fine with. Do I setup a stream analytics job and then route the new consumer group to that job?

Comment: Yes, do this temporary integration with ASA job and watch its metrics or enable a Diagnostics logs for blob storage. This temporary stream pipe allows to you watch all events in the real-time from their ingestion and consuming.